# why does "capturing" an image of a VM in Azure prevent the VM from being used?

Tags: azure

The Azure portal web interface has several options for creating 'images' of a VM including:

- *snapshot* creates a snapshot of the machine which can presumably be restored or copied (what I am trying to do without much success so far)
- *capture* generalises a VM into an image that can be used to create multiple VMs (in theory)

The capture option makes the original VM unusable. In fact you are prompted about whether you want to keep it as it will no longer run (which indeed it can't).

Why is capture a destructive operation?

Comment: More to the point... why the f*** isn't there a warning that it's a destructive operation?  Did this as an experiment... what a mistake... no warning.... just... "you can't start that perfectly fine VM anymore, l thank you very much"   Aaaargh!

Comment: I ran into this today (3 years later)!  No warning.  Also, every time I try to create a new VM from the image, it fails and says "OS Provisioning for VM 'blah' did not finish in the allotted time. However, the VM guest agent was detected running. This suggests the guest OS has not been properly prepared to be used as a VM image.

Answer (score 0):

When you generalise an image using sysprep it will remove the customisation from your VM and that particular VM be of no use except as a golden image. This golden image then can be used as a template to spin more VM’s by passing on the missing parameters which sysprep removed.

If you like to keep the VM, you are using for capture it is recommended that you make a copy of it first and then use it for capture and sysprep process
Refer below for details

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource

Snapshot is more of a VM state at a given point in time and. Mostly used for migration to another region or to capture a state of an application running the VM before an application upgrade or patch.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question. Why is capture implemented as an "in place" operation on the VM rather than something done on an automatically created copy instead?

Comment: Great question Bruce. Could be a suggestion we can pass on to the Microsoft product team. I will see if I can create a ticket for it( have never done this before :-))   Any how When you run sysprep it runs all operations on the active VM before capturing it at the end

Comment: Can you help with this one? https://serverfault.com/questions/1029522/azure-move-restore-a-vm-from-a-backup-what-is-a-plan

Comment: Are you planning to use snapshot or can you use backup? If you can use azure backup then I think it be easy with cross region replication.  If snapshot is must for you because of process you need to follow, I can look into it. I will get back to you tomorrow

Comment: Another point here is that sysprep is Windows only. What if anything is done for a Linux image? The logic of removing security information should still apply. Do they use [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/virt-sysprep.1.html)